# How to fix an error message when installing mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, pycharm, mod-wsgi

when I type pip install mod_wsgi in my pycharm terminal(venv activated), an error is shown below , I have mod_wsgi on python 38(which is already in used with 1 of the project in apache) and I am trying to install mod_wsgi on my python 39 (so that I can use it on my other project) but fail. Anyone can help me solve the error?

error:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SCS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xs0tks5n\\mod-wsg
i_694922b5703e498c8e79a9fa99786895\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SCS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xs0tks5n\\mod-wsgi_694922b5703e498c8e79a9fa99786895\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__)
 if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SC
S\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r1pp8vy9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include\site\python3.9\mod-wsgi'
         cwd: C:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs0tks5n\mod-wsgi_694922b5703e498c8e79a9fa99786895\
    Complete output (215 lines):
    running install
    c:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.9
    creating build\temp.win32-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src\server
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\Rel
ease\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
    mod_wsgi.c
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    src/server\mod_wsgi.c(1331): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'Py_ssize_t', possible loss of data
    src/server\mod_wsgi.c(1624): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'apr_off_t' to 'std::apr_size_t', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_apache.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_apache.obj
    wsgi_apache.c
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_buckets.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9
\Release\src/server\wsgi_buckets.obj
    wsgi_buckets.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_convert.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9
\Release\src/server\wsgi_convert.obj
    wsgi_convert.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_daemon.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_daemon.obj
    wsgi_daemon.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_interp.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_interp.obj
    wsgi_interp.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_logger.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_logger.obj
    wsgi_logger.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_memory.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_memory.obj
    wsgi_memory.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_metrics.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9
\Release\src/server\wsgi_metrics.obj
    wsgi_metrics.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    src/server\wsgi_metrics.c(478): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'apr_time_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
    src/server\wsgi_metrics.c(609): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'apr_time_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
    src/server\wsgi_metrics.c(390): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'apr_uint64_t', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_restrict.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.
9\Release\src/server\wsgi_restrict.obj
    wsgi_restrict.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_server.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_server.obj
    wsgi_server.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_stream.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_stream.obj
    wsgi_stream.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_thread.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.9\
Release\src/server\wsgi_thread.obj
    wsgi_thread.c
    c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\include\os.h(44): warning C4005: 'PLATFORM': macro redefinition
    c:\users\scs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\include\pyconfig.h(300): note: see previous definition of 'PLATFORM'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/include -Ic:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include -IC:\Users
\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /Tcsrc/server\wsgi_validate.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.
9\Release\src/server\wsgi_validate.obj
    wsgi_validate.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\libs /LIBPATH:C:\
Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32 /LIBPATH:c:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\PCbuild\win32 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86 /EXPORT:PyInit_mod_wsgi build\temp.win32-3.9\Releas
e\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_apache.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_buckets.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_convert.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server
\wsgi_daemon.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_interp.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_logger.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_memory.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_metri
cs.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_restrict.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_server.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_stream.obj build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_thread.obj bu
ild\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\wsgi_validate.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\mod_wsgi.cp39-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.cp39-win32.lib C:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
\Python39-32/libs/python39.lib C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/lib/libhttpd.lib C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/lib/libapr-1.lib C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/lib/libaprutil-1.lib C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46/lib/libaprico
nv-1.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.cp39-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.9\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.cp39-win32.exp
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_brigade_flatten@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_thread_mutex_create@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_ipsubnet_test@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pool_cleanup_register@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_palloc@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_satisfies@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_getword_conf@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pstrndup@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_threadkey_private_create@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_hash_overlay@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_remote_host@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_document_root@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_some_auth_required@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_no2slash@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_brigade_create@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_strerror@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_table_make@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_check_cmd_context@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_brigade_destroy@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_table_elts@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_brigade@24
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_array_push@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_server_port@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_brigade_cleanup@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_array_append@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_scoreboard_global@0
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_ipsubnet_create@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pstrdup@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_strtoi64@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_limit_req_body@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_table_add@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_escape_html2@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_thread_mutex_lock@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_sockaddr_info_get@24
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_hook_handler@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_register_provider@20
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_discard_request_body@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pool_userdata_set@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_find_path_info@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_regexec@20
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_pregsub@20
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_transient_create@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_add_version_component@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_psprintf
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_hook_access_checker@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_add_cgi_vars@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_table_unset@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_psignature@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_thread_mutex_unlock@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_allow_options@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_server_name@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_hook_child_init@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_dynamic_fn_retrieve@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_set_content_type@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_log_error_
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pool_userdata_get@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pstrcat
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_flush_create@4
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_type_eos
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_off_t_toa@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_log_rerror_
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_array_make@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_hash_get@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_hook_post_config@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_table_get@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_run_generate_log_id@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_pass_brigade@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pstrmemdup@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_table_setn@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_pregcomp@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_stat@16
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_array_cat@8
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_table_set@12
    mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_pool_cleanup_null
    wsgi_apache.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_conv_utf8_to_ucs2@16
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_shared_make@20
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_shared_copy
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_free
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_alloc
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_shared_destroy@4
    wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_bucket_shared_split
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_show_mpm@0
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_hash_pool_get@4
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_hash_next@4
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_hash_this@16
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_hash_first@8
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_server_description@0
    wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_server_built@0
    wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_scoreboard_process@4
    wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_get_scoreboard_worker_from_indexes@8
    wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ap_exists_scoreboard_image@0
    wsgi_thread.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_threadkey_private_get@8
    wsgi_thread.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__apr_threadkey_private_set@8
    build\lib.win32-3.9\mod_wsgi\server\mod_wsgi.cp39-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 106 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SCS\\AppData\\Local\\Te
mp\\pip-install-xs0tks5n\\mod-wsgi_694922b5703e498c8e79a9fa99786895\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SCS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xs0tks5n\\mod-wsgi_694922b5703e498c8e79a9fa99786895\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize
, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'
))' install --record 'C:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r1pp8vy9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\scs\pycharmprojects\role_based_login_system-master\venv\include\sit
e\python3.9\mod-wsgi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having may be caused by mixing 32- bit programs with 64-bit programs. The programs you're using must all be 64-bit or all be 32-bit. They cannot be mixed. If your OS is 64-bit it is recommended that you use 64-bit.

Decide to continue with 64-bit or 32-bit. Remove / uninstall the programs that aren't the same as the bit you've decided to use. Reinstall that program using the same bit as the other programs.

Comment: so my python, pycharm and the XAMPP must be all 64 bit?

Comment: not necessarily 64 bit, they must all match each other and preferably match your computer.  Your python pycharm and XAMPP must all be the same so either all 64 or all 32. If your computer is 64-bit you have the option of using either 64 bit applications or 32 bit, but this option is what can cause mixed applications to exist on the same computer. If your computer is 32 bit everything must be 32 bit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).